# How to log in to an external page using java?

Tags: java, jsp, jira

I want to log in to JIRA from a java program (specifically from a jsp page). When I click on a link, the page should fetch the authentication details which I have stored in a java class (AuthenticationDetails.java). Then it should add it to the JIRA page login request. Finally I should be able to enter JIRA without inputting the authentication manually. The jsp page is triggered by an external html page.

Here is the code I am using.

```
<%@page import="org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="com.test.AuthenticationDetails"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.http.*"%>

<%!String username = "";
    String password = "";%>
<%
    username = AuthenticationDetails.USERNAME;
    password = AuthenticationDetails.PASSWORD;

    String headerKey="Authorization";
    String headerValue="Basic"+Base64.encodeBase64String((username+":"+password).getBytes());
    response.setHeader(headerKey,headerValue);
    response.sendRedirect("https://jira.xxx.yyy.com/login.jsp");

%>
```

But this redirects me to the login page again. Why is it not getting automatically logged in? I am fairly new to java and working on this project and have never worked on applications that required web access. I know this is specific to JIRA, but can I do it for other websites as well, let's say gmail etc.? In JIRA, I noticed that the username and password are passed as `os_username` and `os_password`when I looked into the query.

This seemed to work when I had tried to login to a login page I created in my machine.

Comment: Did you check the JIRA for such SSO login? See [more](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/no.kantega.kerberosauth.kerberosauth-plugin)

Comment: I am not familiar with that. If you can explain it, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web scraping and automation was what I was looking for. The JIRA Rest client helped me in only getting data from JIRA. Using a library like Jaunt, login can be automated. The library helps in achieving this without requiring to know all the underlying details, like http headers, responses and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Authors of JIRA give few webservices API, assume this is official and secure way to exchange data. learning this technique is good investment for other projects too.

Such "login hacking" to front-end page have no sense since very few years

REST

https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis

SOAP

https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/creating-a-jira-soap-client

and others too

Comment: From what I understand (correct me if I am wrong), the REST and SOAP apis will help me fetch the data I require from JIRA. But do these help apis help me to redirect the page that is displayed after login?

Comment: SOAP is old, some fat but generate type-safe code (i like it), REST(+JSON) new fashion, use not together but there are competitive technologies. Both have nothing to redirect, but to use her (his) data in Your pages (hosted at Your JSP server)

Comment: This is something I would probably need. But how do I go about doing the original stuff that I wanted? I have a generic username and password that can be used for everybody. So when they click on the link, instead of taking them to the login page, I would like to automatically do that and direct them to the page after login.